# WARNING : unexpected return value : 'undefined' returned by 'custom' validator (ExpressJS)

Tags: node.js, validation, express

I'm just learn about NodeJS using ExpressJS and now I'm ltrying to understand about custom validator with express-validator.
I'm make a custom validator to check username availability. But on console it returns:

> WARNING : unexpected return value : 'undefined' returned by  'custom' validator

But I see on my coding and I'm sure there is no any mistake. All values are returned but custom validator seems not working anymore.

This is my custom validator:

```
app.use(validator({
    customValidators : {
        cekUsername : function(value){
            sql = 'SELECT COUNT(username) as "username" from tbpengguna WHERE username='+mysql.escape(value)+';';
            koneksi.query(sql, function(e, rows, f){
                console.log(rows[0].username);
                return rows[0].username == 0;
            }); 
        }
    }
}));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is quite expected since you don't return anything for your validator function, you only return inside the callback function.

The solution would be to return a Promise that will return the Boolean value when the promise is resolved.

Comment: Thank You... I works now using Promise. But at express-validator readme file, I don't see it using a promise to make a custom validator. And I'm just read about Promise. I guest it must use a promise because it's async process (koneksi.query method). Am I right?

Comment: Yes. the express-validator, can work with promises too https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator/issues/318

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm really missed too much thing :D